# how to update userprofile password in laravel5

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

when i am update my password in my profile page the password should be changed almost its working fine.but i am not entered any password in the field on that time i click submit button automatically password should generated in db.suggest me something

my html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="loginForm" method="POST" action="{{ url('updatepassword') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="post-content col-sm-12">
        <h3 class="post-title">Change Password</h3>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password"  class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5 mm">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password"   class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-flat ">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function updatepassword(Request $request)
{
    $user =new User;
    $user->where('email', '=' ,Auth::user()->email)
      ->update([ 'password' => Hash::make('secret')]);
    return Redirect::to('user_profile');
}
```

router:

```
Route::post('updatepassword',array('as' =>'password','uses' => 'UserController@updatepassword'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a random password if one isn't submitted, you can do:

```
$password = Input::has('password') ? Hash::make( Input::get('password') ) : Hash::make( str_random(8) );
```

This will check if a password was submitted, and if not, it will generate a random 8 character password.

Then:

```
$user =new User;
$user->where('email', '=' ,Auth::user()->email)->update([ 'password' => $password ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If user does not entered any password first you need to make client side on form as well as server side validation.

```
public function updatepassword(Request $request)
{
    $user =new User;
    if(!$request->has('password')){
      return redirect()->withStatus('password field is blank');
    }
    $user->where('email', '=' ,Auth::user()->email)
      ->update([ 'password' => Hash::make($request->has('password'))]);


    return Redirect::to('user_profile')->withStatus('Password has been successfully updated.');
}
```